# Get number of records in child table

Tags: mysql

I need to get number of record in child table.

Parent table

```
+-------------+------------+  
| Id          | Name       |  
+-------------+------------+  
| 1           | a          |  
+-------------+------------+    
| 2           | b          |    
+-------------+------------+ 
| 3           | c          | 
+-------------+------------+
```

Child table:

```
+-------------+------------+  
| Id          | Code       |  
+-------------+------------+
| 1           | d1         |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 1           | d2         | 
+-------------+------------+    
| 1           | d3         |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 1           | d1         | 
+-------------+------------+    
| 2           | d2         |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 2           | d3         | 
+-------------+------------+ 
| 3           | d1         |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 3           | d2         | 
+-------+-----+------------+
```

Result should like:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+ 
| Id          | Name       | NumOfRec   |  
+-------------+------------+------------+ 
| 1           | a          |        4   |
+-------------+------------+------------+  
| 2           | b          |        2   |
+-------------+------------+------------+  
| 3           | c          |        2   |
+-------------+------------+ -----------+
```

I've tried with COUNT but then I get only number of records for one id but not for other ID's.

Comment: Refer my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS RECCOUNT FROM CHILD_TABLE
GROUP BY ID;
```

To get the records based on PARENT ID, you can do,

```
SELECT P.ID, P.NAME, COUNT(C.ID) FROM
PARENT P LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILD C
ON P.ID = C.ID
GROUP BY P.ID, P.NAME;
```

**SQL FIDDLE HERE** : **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/08d58/3**

Left outer join results in number of records as 0 for parent ids not having corresponding child records.

Comment: Is is possible to somehow speed up executing of this query? It tooks some time? Or it is normal for table that consist more than 260 000 rows?

Comment: @Josef: Refer edited query. For the speed, You need to have primary key foreign key constraint for the ID Field.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GROUP BY clause to group the result by every distinct value of id. This should do it

To get the edited result, you've got to join the parent table.

```
SELECT 
    parent.id,
    parent.Name, 
    parent.other_columns_that_you_need,
    COUNT(id) as NumOfRec 
FROM 
    child 
INNER JOIN
    parent
ON
    parent.id = child.id
GROUP BY 
    parent.id
```

**Note**

In standard SQL you will have to group by all columns without an aggregate function. MySQL has got [extended the use of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html) and you can omit those columns with the same values. This is here valid, because all not aggregated columns are directly dependent of the parent id.

Answer (score 1):

use `group by`

```
select count(*) as NumOfRec  , id from <Child table> group by id;
```

For your updated question, this should work:

```
select parent.id,parent.name,numOdRec from parent join (
    select count(*) as NumOfRec  , id from <Child table> group by id) as childs on childs.id=parent.id
```

Comment: Yes, but i forgot to add one more additional columns, see my edited post. From parent table i should have output Id, Name and from child tablet number of recrods that matches to Id from parent table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Writing query with count will give you solutions

```
select distinct a.id,count(b.id) from parent a, child b where a.id=b.id;
```

Comment: You should try to avoid code only answers and provide some extra information to explain why this works and what happens.