# Count the number of Records in Child in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, foreign-keys

I want to achieve the same result as the below question but in MVC.

```
    public ActionResult Index()

    {
        //List<Systems> systems;
        //var query = db.SystemFamily.Select(c => c.SystemFamilyID).ToList();
        //foreach (var sid in query)
        //{
        //    systems = db.Systems.Select(c => c.SystemFamilyID == sid).ToList();
        //}
        //int count = systems.Count();//Here you will  get count

        //ViewBag.Counts = count; 
        var viewmodel = new Sys_SysFam();
        foreach (var item in db.SystemFamily)
        {
            int id = item.SystemFamilyID;

            //SystemsCount 
            int count = db.Systems.Where(x => x.SystemFamilyID == id).Count();   // Here while debugging it has the value for id but throws exception. 
            item.SystemsCount = count;
        }
        ViewBag.Count = db.SystemFamily.Where(x=>x.deleteFlag==false).Count();   //All these work
        int count1 =db.Systems.Count();    // I even tried it with a where condition passing a SystemFamilyID. Even that worked
        ViewBag.SCount = count1;
        return View(db.SystemFamily.Where(x=>x.deleteFlag==false).ToList());
    }
```

I get exception

*An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code*

*Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
This is the inner exception

There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.*

[this is the result that needs to be achieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053960/get-number-of-records-in-child-table/32627218)

Comment: the provided link is dead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053960/get-number-of-records-in-child-table/32627218#32627218

Comment: The 3rd table is what i want to achieve..

Comment: Typically the `DbContext` should be short lived, can you post the code how you're instanciating `db`?

Comment: The DbContext is instantiated at the beginning of my controller. ` private SystemsContext db = new SystemsContext();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception you are getting is basically that you are executing a query while iterating over the results from another query.

in your code try in the foreach statement

```
      foreach (var item in db.SystemFamily.ToList())
      {
        int id = item.SystemFamilyID;

        //SystemsCount 
        int count = db.Systems.Where(x => x.SystemFamilyID == id).Count();   
        item.SystemsCount = count;
     }
```

Or you can allow MARS in your connection string Add **MultipleActiveResultSets=true** to the provider part of your connection string (where Data Source, Initial Catalog, etc. are specified).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! i have been doing a lot of stuff for the last 2 hours to get it right..

Comment: But just for my curiosity : `ViewBag.Count = db.SystemFamily.Where(x=>x.deleteFlag==false).Count();
            //int count1 =
            int x1 = db.Systems.Where(x => x.SystemFamilyID == 2).Count();
            ViewBag.SCount = db.SystemFamily.Where(x => x.SystemFamilyID == 2).Count(); `  why does this work if count works only on list?

Comment: because that is outside of the foreach statement. With the ToList() it will do the full query, and load every item into memory prior to doing the foreach. This is good in the way that you have your data access over all in one go, which could be beneficial if you will be referring to the enumerable multiple times within the method (which is what you are doing) or don't want to keep the connection open for long.

Comment: i would like to know why it works only when the loop iterates through a list and not the way i did?

Comment: @ViniVasundharan In your foreach, you send a query into database for each item, so it always has that connection open in the context of the foreach.

Comment: OK. Now i get it . That is the reason why i am getting an inner exception a DataReader is open. Thanks a lot for your explanation and time..